# Second Derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

I applied Cauchy Theorem on integral and it is of third grade.
Now I  have to find the Second derivative of equation $$\left(\frac{e^z}{z-1}\right)''.$$
Can anyone help me for the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case A: You mean $\displaystyle \frac{e^z}{z}-1$.

We rewrite as $z^{-1}e^{z}-1$.

Taking the first derivative, we have $-z^{-2}e^{z}+z^{-1}e^{z}$.

Taking the second derivative, we have $2z^{-3}e^{z}-z^{-2}e^{z}-z^{-2}e^{z}+z^{-1}e^{z}$.

This simplifies to $\boxed{\displaystyle \frac{e^z}{z}-\frac{2e^z}{z^2}+\frac{2e^z}{z^3}}$.

---

Case B: You mean $\displaystyle \frac{e^z}{z-1}$.

Rewrite as $(z-1)^{-1}e^{z}$.

Taking the first derivative, we have $-(z-1)^{-2}e^{z}+(z-1)^{-1}e^{z}$.

Taking the second derivative, we have $2(z-1)^{-3}e^{z}-(z-1)^{-2}e^{z}-(z-1)^{-2}e^{z}+(z-1)^{-1}e^{z}$.

This simplifies to $\boxed{\displaystyle \frac{e^z}{z-1}-\frac{2e^z}{(z-1)^2}+\frac{2e^z}{(z-1)^3}}$.